# Prove that f is a bijection then prove that p is an odd prime then prove the rest part

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $A = {1, 2, . . . , p − 1}$. Prove that there is a bijection $f$ from $A$ onto $A$ such that $kf(k) ≡ 1 (mod p)$ for each $k ∈ A$.Hence deduce that if $p$ is an odd prime, then $p$ divides the numerator
> of $1 + \frac 12 + · · · + \frac 1{p − 1}$.

Here is my argument

To prove that there is a bijection $f$ from $A$ onto $A$ such that $kf(k) ≡ 1 (mod p)$ for each $k ∈ A$, we can define $f(k) = a$, where $a$ is the unique integer in $A$ such that $k*a ≡ 1 (mod p)$. Such an integer $a$ exists for each $k ∈ A$ because $p$ is a prime and therefore each element $k ∈ A$ has a unique inverse modulo $p$.

To prove that $f$ is a bijection, we need to show that it is both injective and surjective. To show that $f$ is injective, suppose that $f(k_1) = f(k_2)$ for some $k_1$, $k_2$ $∈ A$. Then, by definition, $k_1*f(k_1) ≡ 1 (mod p)$ and $k_2*f(k_2) ≡ 1 (mod p)$. Multiplying the first congruence by $k_2$ and the second by $k_1$, we get $k_1*k_2*f(k_1) ≡ k_2 (mod p)$ and $k_1*k_2*f(k_2) ≡ k_1 (mod p)$. Subtracting these congruences gives $(k_1*k_2)(f(k_1) - f(k_2)) ≡ 0 (mod p)$. Since $p$ is a prime and $k_1$, $k_2$ are not divisible by $p$, we must have $f(k_1) = f(k_2)$.

To show that $f$ is surjective, note that for each $k ∈ A$, there is an integer $a ∈ A$ such that $k*a ≡ 1 (mod p)$, so $f(k) = a$ is defined for each $k ∈ A$. Therefore, $f$ is a well-defined function from $A$ onto $A$.

Is this okay for first part? And how to solve for second part?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for the first part seems good, although the well-definedness comment would make a lot more sense in your first paragraph.  A function being well-defined just means that given two equivalent inputs we have the same output.  Well-definedness is not an issue in your example because given any two elements of $A$ their output will always be the same.  An example of a non-well-defined function would be $f([n]) = n$ where $[n]$ is the equivalence class of $n \mod p$, in such a case you would have $[n+p] = [n]$ yet $f([n]) \neq f([n+p])$.  Sorry for the possible aside, it was just something I noticed.

For part two, the hint I will give is to notice that the condition in the first part showed you how to express $1 \mod p$ as something multiplied by any element of $A$.  Maybe there is some clever way to eliminate the denominators using this observation.  And, hypothetically once you have gotten rid of the denominators you can use the fact that the prime we are considering is odd, meaning $p-1$ is even.